# Verify two values are contained in separate arraylists at the same index

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

I have two ArrayLists: phNumbers and pinNumbers. Both with the same amount of elements. I am trying to check if a given value is in the first phNumbers, and if it is, at what index of the phNumbers ArrayList was that value found. I then wish to check if a second value is in the pinNums ArrayList at the index previously identified.

Here is my code so at the moment:

```
for(int i = 0; i < phNumbers.size() && i < pinNums.size(); i++){
    index1 = phNumbers.indexOf(i);
    index2 = phNumbers.indexOf(i);
    index3 = pinNums.indexOf(i);
    if(phNumbers.get(i).equals(details[1].trim()) && pinNums.get(index1+1).equals(details[2].trim())){
        //send response1
    }
    else if(phNumbers.get(i).equals(details[1].trim()) && !pinNums.get(index2+1).equals(details[2].trim())){
        //send response2
    }
    else if(pinNums.get(i).equals(details[2].trim()) && !phNumbers.get(index3+1).equals(details[1].trim())){
        //Send response3
    }
    else{
        //send response4
    }
}
```

The issue I am having is that it is not working for any elements beyond the first, so I'm assuming it's an issue with my for loop. Could anyone offer some assistance?

Comment: Please provide a complete example. What are `phNumbers` and `pinNums`? What is `details`? Are you sure `phNumbers.indexOf(i)` is what you want to do? Have you debugged your code? If not, why not? If yes, where did it go wrong?

Comment: your code and question are not proper...please try to elabotate

Comment: @MaxVollmer I explained in my question that phNumbers and pinNums are ArrayLists. Details is just a String I have split to get values. As far as I'm aware the indexOf() method returns the index at which a value resides.

Comment: `ArrayList` is a raw type. Do you use raw `ArrayList`s? If yes, **don't**. If not, you haven't answered my question. Again: Please update your question with a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

So, First if you have a phNumber arraylist and one string of phnumber then try this

```
 ArrayList<String> phNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
        phNumbers.add("aaa");
        phNumbers.add("bbb");
        phNumbers.add("ccc");
        phNumbers.add("ddd");
        ArrayList<String> pinNums = new ArrayList<>();
        pinNums.add("ddd");
        pinNums.add("bbb");
        pinNums.add("ccc");
        pinNums.add("aaa");
        for (int i = 0; i < phNumbers.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = i; j < pinNums.size(); j++) {
                if (phNumbers.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(pinNums.get(j))) {
                    Log.e("mye", "phone number and pin number match on this index" + i + "for phnumber and index " + j + "for pin number");
                }
            }
        }
```

if you want to break after some point then you need to break for loop.
its ok or you want anything else?

Comment: I need to make sure the values are at the same index in the ArrayList. E.g: ArrayList1 first value = Tim    and ArrayList2 first value is 45. The contains method will only tell me whether the values are in the ArrayList, not whether they are opposite each other